# Django Forum App, comments don't update on user-side, but can be seen through admin

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

For reference, here are my models in my Forum app:

```
class Forum(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('forum-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

To display the forum posts, I have a CBV 'ForumListView':

```
class ForumListView(ListView):
    model = Forum
    template_name = 'forum/forum.html'
    context_object_name = 'forum_posts'
    ordering = ['-created_at']
```

From this list, the user can click on any forum and it will lead them to 'forum-detail' with the CBV 'ForumDetailView':

```
class ForumDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Forum

    extra_context = {
        'comments': Comment.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')}
```

Here is where I passed in the comments from my Comment model to be shown alongside the post. **I think** this is the reason why the comments don't update, but I'm not too sure how to fix this.

In the template for forum_detail.html, this is how I display all the comments made:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
        {% if comment.forum == forum %}
        <div class="content-section">
            <p>{{ comment.description }}</p>
            <small>{{ comment.user.username }}, on {{ comment.created_at|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Note that the *new* comment made will be shown if I re-run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and sometimes the *new* comment appears after a few minutes of waiting/refreshing the page.

Also, I think function-based views may fix this, however I have coded my entire app with CBVs and would love a fix that doesn't involve re-coding everything!

Any help is greatly appreciated, and can provide more info/code if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting it in `extra_context` like this will cause the queryset to be evaluated when you define the view, and any values that it has at that time will be the only values that the view will get. That's why it is working when you restart the server. So it should be dynamic and fetched every time a new request comes. In that case you need to put it in `get_context_data`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['comments'] = Comment.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')}
    return context
```

Comment: I was actually just working on that now so my updated ForumDetailView looks basically like that, but it still doesn't update immediately.

EDIT: sorry mate about the extra comments, just tried it with ur exact code and. it works now. thanks so much!